# Folder Location - Installed Program

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have an installed program that manages my keyboard. On installation, it created a folder within Documents. I have moved this and even deleted it, but opening the app/program recreates it. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program, and there is no option to specify the preferred location. I have also tried hiding the folder, but that seems to interfere with the functionality somehow. Is there a way, perhaps through the Registry, to specify where this folder will go? I am using Windows 11.

Note: This is not the installation files for the program itself, but contains saved information related to the keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like the program is coded to use the Documents directory, modify the registry if that’s true, would be a pointless endeavor

Comment: Without the program's name, there is not much that we can even attempt to do.

Comment: @harrymc The program is Vissles 84-Keys which is the management software for the Vissles keyboard.

Comment: I have not found any documentation about such an option, so it's extremely unlikely that it can be switched without doing a binary hack of the executable itself (not recommended).

Comment: Thank you @harrymc. It looks like I will just have to live with it, or get a better keyboard!